# Looping through a collection of li elements adding a z-index and incrementing value on each

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do what I thought would be a simple task of checking a content slider div looking for the li elements, and adding a z-index to to each one, incrementing the value by one each time.

So for a collection of three li elements they would be assigned:

`<li style="z-index:1"></li>
 <li style="z-index:2"></li>
 <li style="z-index:3"></li>`

I have tried doing this by using the following code:

```
  var $lis = $('#contentSlider ul li');

                  for(var i = 0; i < $lis.length; ++i){

                      $lis:eq(1).css('z-index',1);              
                  }
```

And also tried using:

```
var $lis = $('#contentSlider ul li');

                  for(var i = 0; i < $lis.length; ++i){


                    $('li').index($lis); 

                  }
```

Any idea how would be best to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each) method:

```
$('#contentSlider ul li').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).css('z-index', i + 1);
});
```

You supply a function to the `each` method.  This function is run once for each element in the selection.  Each time it is called, it is passed the element's position in the selection (the index) as the first argument and the element itself as the second argument.  We need to add `1` to `i` because it is 0-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply like this

```
$('#contentSlider li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).css('z-index', index);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/zgYWK/