# Looping through elements and adding a decreasing z-index

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to stack a group of elements in decreasing order with z-index.

So for a collection of three li elements they would look like:

```
<li style="z-index:3"></li>
<li style="z-index:2"></li>
<li style="z-index:1"></li>
```

So far i've found the method explained here [Looping through a collection of li elements adding a z-index and incrementing value on each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787693/)
seems very close:

```
$('#contentSlider ul li').each(function(i, el) {
   $(el).css('z-index', i + 1);
});
```

And at this stage im guessing i can use `$("#contentSlider ul li").length;` in some way to count down with `('z-index', i - 1);` but beyond that I'm stuck.

Comment: Well, you already know how to do it. What happened when you tried?

Comment: i was getting z-index:-1, 0, 1, 2... I think it was because I couldn’t work out how to pass the length into the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to know how to do it already... Maybe this is what you want?

```
var lis = $('#contentSlider ul li');
lis.each(function(i, el){
   $(el).css('z-index', lis.length-i);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That does the trick and makes the most simple sense to me being the noob I am. 

I had the theory I was just missing the syntax. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is absolutely correct.  You can do:

```
var zIndex = $('#contentSlider ul li').length;
$('#contentSlider ul li').each(function(i, el) {
   $(el).css('z-index', zIndex);
   zIndex--;
});
```

Here is a working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/HVs6N/